# Working with cypress redirect

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

Situation: 
I am writing test automation for a website. There comes a point where there is a link button on my website. Clicking this I am redirected to an external website. There I have to log in and as soon as I do that I am redirected to my original web-page which contains some 'connections' that I need.

Problem:
As soon as cypress clicks on the redirection button it does into a blank page.

Ideal solution:
I would want to automate the entire scenario. If not then at-least a work around.

Comment: which "redirection link" are you referring to 
"does into a blank page"? You mention two in the question

Comment: @bkucera It should go to a login website like facebook.com but it says 'data:,' in the url section and blank page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#External-Navigation), you should really be using `cy.request()` to log in. You don't control a 3rd party site, and that makes your test very flakey. 
For example, a lot of login pages are constantly changing and are A/B tested for the purpose of **preventing a bot from logging in**, including testing bots. The `data:,` url is probably the result of a http redirect.

Thankfully, using `cy.request()` you can 'fake' logging in by making a request to the server through code (which doesn't change as much) and you will never have to leave your app to log in

Here's a [recipe for Single Sign-On](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Single-Sign-On) for example.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I have found a workaround for my specific case, but technically this solution should work, so I am accepting the answer.

Comment: I read this argumentation in Github issues before and I agree that it is the preferrable option for most tests. But sometimes testing the actual login like the user would do it is the entire point of a test. In that case this work around is sadly not applicable.

Comment: @bkucera I am doing a JS redirect and also see `data:,` in my location bar when I run the tests _headless_ —I see that in the generated video. But everything works fine when I run the tests "headed."